# How to set custom data on html drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I'm trying to set a custom data which is an HTML element on my drag event.
So far I did this:

```
element.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
  event.dataTransfer.setData('custom-data', document.querySelector('.the-element')
})

dropzone.addEventListener('drop', event => {
  const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('custom-data') // this is empty
})
```

Is there a way to do this?

I already tried to do `JSON.stringify` on the element before passing it to the drag event. but `JSON.stringify` does not work on HTMLElement object

This [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#custom) from mdn says it is possible to use custom data

Comment: Exactly what do you want? You want to transfer data during drag and drop?

Comment: @TanDuong yes. and the data is and HTMLElement. But there is no data type for that. I tried to do `'application/json'` but I got `[object HTMLElement]` as a result

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#html), you can specify the data type `text/html` and pass a well-formed HTML string. If you want to use an existing element in the DOM, you could pass its [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) string property.

Comment: But I will lose reference if I use the outerHTML

Comment: @bobharley From what I can see [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Recommended_drag_types#node), Firefox may offer the ability to drag and drop a node reference. I do not know which other browsers, if any, also support that feature.